# CABasic Animation on iPhone X causes "Warping" of Rasterised Layers

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, cabasicanimation, rasterize

I am creating an App that uses CABasic Animation on Sublayers of a UIView.

Scaling and Position Animations are involved and the Layers are CAShapeLayers with `shouldRasterize` set to `true` for smooth Animation.

This works, but on the iPhone X, Layers with Dark Colours such as UIColor(red: 0, green: 35/255, blue: 9/255, alpha: 1) appear to "warp" during the Animation.

This does NOT happen on other iPhones including the 7 Plus and 6 Plus, nor does it happen in the Simulator.

This also does NOT happen on the iPhone X if `shouldRasterize` is set to `false`, nor does it affect lighter coloured Layers.

Has anyone encountered this and/or have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this actually happens in all Apps with dark colours and black, as a result of the delay in turning on/off pixels when black is required.

The only way to avoid this is to use a dark colour instead of black, with an RGB value of at least 20, which basically means the pixels don't turn off, so you have to decide whether battery-saving true black or motion is more important.